# Why doesn't this custom submit work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit, keyboard-events

I have this button which submits the login form:

```
<input class="btn btn-large btn-success" id="login-button" onclick="handleLogin()" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
```

And I have this function which I want to use to have a custom submit when the user presses enter:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $(document).keyup(function(event) { 

        if(event.which == 13) {

            $('#login-button').click();
            //event.preventDefault();
            //return false;
        }
    });
});
```

However this doesn't do anything at all. I have tried with and without the commented part of the code. 
Note that the submission of the form works when clicking and that I don't have my input fields inside `form` element. I am using handleLogin() to submit using AJAX. **So all I really want is this `#login-button` to get clicked!** Do you guys see the problem? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I'm using Chrome BETA channel.

**IMPORTANT!: I want #login-button to get clicked when pressing ENTER. Nothing more that that. I already know how to submit a form.**

Comment: What is the `handleLogin` function that is attached to the click event?

Comment: Also, what browser are you using? IE < 9 doesn't recognize `event.which`.

Comment: @Oded there's nothing wrong with that function. That's been tested and all. That function sends everything to the server side. My problem is that the button doesn't get clicked.

Comment: there is a missing `});`

Comment: @ajax333221 yes I fixed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### *[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/vmYNU/2/)*

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
     $(document).keyup(function(event) {  
        if(event.keyCode === 13) {

            $('#yourForm').submit(); // submit form
             alert('yeah!')
          
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }          
     });     
});
```

use: `keyCode` instead of `which`
use: `.submit()` with the `name` or `id` of your form. http://api.jquery.com/submit/
You were missing a `});`

Comment: I totally understand your answer and it's a very nice one. But really I just want that login-button to get clicked. And that keycode isn't working either. My ENTER doesn't get recognized.

Comment: @Loolooii ;) you're welcome (P.S use `which` to distinguish MOUSE types)

Answer (score 1):

here a better way to handle submit form events:

```
<form id="form">
...
//input texts ...
...
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

then, the jquery (you don't need know the pressed key, only the **submit** event dispatched by the submit button or the enter key):

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
//your logic ...
});
```

Comment: I already mentioned that I don't use any form element. By clicking the login button that handleLogin() is triggered which handles everything. I don't need any form and now I just want that button to get clicked when clicking enter? Please read my question.

Comment: use form in order to keep a good semantic, the most important reason for keep form element is because submit button causes form trigger submit event (send all elements inside form tag)